# Change the sort order of order details in email magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Hi am using magento to my project and the version is  ver. 1.7.0.2

I have to change sort order of details displayed in cart in email sent and the admin panel

Now the details are displaying like

```
Subtotal    RS. 429.00

Shipping & Handling RS. 40.00

Grand Total (Excl.Tax)  RS. 469.00

IN-Rate (14.5%)

RS. 62.21

Tax

RS. 62.21

Grand Total (Incl.Tax)  RS. 531.21
```

**I Want like**

```
Subtotal    RS. 429.00

IN-Rate (14.5%) 

RS. 62.21

Tax

RS. 62.21

Total (Incl.Tax)    RS. 491.21

Shipping & Handling RS. 40.00

Grand Total RS. 531.21
```

Answer (score 0):

Login to admin panel and go to: System->Configuration->SALES/Sales->Checkout Total Sort Order.

And put the sort order value as per your requirement.

If you are not able to update PHTML file then go for override block, follow these simple step to override block.

Copy: `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Totals.php`

Paste: `app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Totals.php`

Copy: `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Totals.php`

Paste: `app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Totals.php`

Now open above files after pasting and edit `protected function _initTotals()` function. Change position according to requirement.

**NOTE: You need to edit files which is in `local` directory**

Hope will help!

Comment: This will work only for front end not for emails and admin panel

Comment: In that case you have to update .phtml file, `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\totals.phtml`

Comment: Open this `totals.phtml` file and you will get simple html and data in object. Format according to requirement.

Comment: there is a foreach loop how can i reorder it

Comment: I have updated the answer to override the admin block with step. follow these steps and just re-order the code as I have mentioned in answer.

Comment: there is no file called  app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Totals.php

Comment: You need to copy `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Totals.php` file and pase it into `local` directory after creating path `app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\`. See the difference `core` and `local`. You need to copy core file and paste it into local directory.

Comment: Have you copied these 2 files and updated `protected function _initTotals()` function?

Comment: Yes i copeid and changed... Any other suggestion

Comment: If you have updated accordingly, then it should work. Try after flushing all cache.

Comment: Why are you editing Adminhtml ? I think you have to override app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Totals.php